# Warum ist dies falscher inhaltlicher Bezug?

Tags: sentence-structure

Im [Wikipediaartikel zu Stilblüten](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stilbl%C3%BCte#Beispiele) wird folgendes Beispiel angegeben:

> Falscher inhaltlicher Bezug: „Für solche faulen Ausreden müssen Sie sich einen Dümmeren suchen, aber den werden Sie kaum finden.“

Warum ist dies falscher inhaltlicher Bezug? Wie würde man es formulieren müssen, um keine Stilblüte zu erzeugen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gemeint ist:

> Sie scheinen mich für so dumm zu halten, dass ich Ihnen Ihre faulen Ausreden abnehme. Sie werden kaum jemanden finden, der so dumm ist.

Gesagt wird aber:

> Sie werden kaum jemanden finden, der dümmer ist als ich.

*...den werden Sie kaum finden...* bezieht sich also auf den falschen Inhalt.

Answer (score 3):

Der Satzteil

> Sie müssen einen Dümmeren finden (als mich), aber den werden Sie kaum
>   finden.

lässt sich interpretieren als:

> Ich bin so dumm, weit und breit werden Sie kaum jemanden finden, der noch dümmer ist als ich.

und ist damit wohl kaum im Sinne des Aussagenden.

Ich sehe zwei Möglichkeiten, das zu korrigieren

> 1) „Für solche faulen Ausreden müssen Sie sich einen Dümmeren suchen.“
>
> 2) „Sie werden kaum jemanden finden, der dumm genug für solch faule
>   Ausreden ist.“

Vielleicht entstand die Stilblüte auch durch Vermischung beider Versionen.

Answer (score 3):

"Dümmer" bezieht sich inhaltlich auf den Sprecher. Man kann den Satz so erweitern:

> Für solche faulen Ausreden müssen Sie sich einen Dümmeren **als mich** suchen, aber den werden Sie kaum finden.

Der Nebensatz bezieht sich auf das Objekt "Dümmeren". Dadurch bekommt der Nebensatz die Bedeutung: "Ich gehöre zu den dümmsten Leuten überhaupt."

Natürlich war das vom Sprecher nicht beabsichtigt. Gemeint war, dass es kaum jemanden geben dürfte, der dumm genug ist, die Ausreden zu glauben. Anders gesagt, wollte der Sprecher "Dümmeren" inhaltlich auf die Ausreden beziehen.

Will man den vollständigen Sinn des Satzes erhalten (also nicht einfach den Nebensatz weglassen), ist es vielleicht am sinnvollsten, den Komparativ durch einen anderen Ausdruck zu ersetzen, z.B.

> Für solche faulen Ausreden müssen Sie sich schon einen ziemlichen Einfaltspinsel suchen.

Answer (score 0):

Den Antworten fehlt bisher der Verbesserungsvorschlag:

> Für solche faulen Ausreden müssen Sie sich einen anderen Suchen, aber jemanden, der dumm genug ist, Ihnen das zu glauben, werden Sie kaum finden.

Das ist aber zu lang. Einfacher wäre es, den Bezug des soweit unspezifische Vergleichs gezielt zu setzen, welcher auf den Redner abstellend und böswillig interpretiert zwar eine Selbstbeleidigung darstellen könnte (die besagte Stilblüte), aber auf den Gegenüber projeziert eine noch stärkere Anfeindung darstellt.

> Für solche faulen Ausreden müssen Sie sich einen anderen Suchen, aber einen Dümmeren als Sie, werden Sie kaum finden.

Der Vergleich "als Sie" ist grammatisch etwas ungehobelt; Vielleicht kam es ursprünglich gerade deshalb zur Auslassung. Ich will aber nicht in Abrede stellen, dass *dümmer als nicht-dumm [=ich]* im Sinne einer einfachen Grammatischen Umformung gemeint gewesen wäre, jedenfalls *gerade dumm genug* gemeint gewesen sein könnte.

Comment: In der Korrekturform habe ich diesen Satz eingangs auch verstanden.